# General inquiry about and Neural Networks Weight Vectors

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying to better understand machine learning principles, but I am sort of stuck on how everything ties together.

For example, I was given as task to classify a group of three patterns.  Each pattern had a target value associated with it (say, 1, 0 and -1 for simplicity).  I put the algorithm through the LMS algorithm.

I calculated the output and the errors:

```
a = w(n) * x(n)    
e(n) = d(n) - w(n)x(n)
```

And then I recalculated the weight vector:

```
w(n+1) = w(n) + alpha*x(n)*e(n)
```

And I did this for all three of the patterns.  I iterated the recalculation of the weight vectors over about 30 times.

Now, what do I do with this new weight vector that I have created?  Do I apply this weight vector to a new set of "testing data"?

Does the "converged" weight vector now become the weight vector to try and classify any unseen data?

With this weight vector, how do I apply it to a new data set?  Where does gradient descent, mean-square errors, and convergence fit into this?

Comment: This is not a neural network, so most NN stuff does not apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Matias mentioned, this is not a neural network --- LMS (which I assume stands for Least Mean Squares here) is closer related to linear methods like linear regression, . Comparatively, the class of neural network models are generally composed of models where you have multiple nodes arranged in a circuit formation, passing input data through several layers of transformations so that the final result is generally a very complex nonlinear function of the input.

With that said: your update step needs to involve a gradient somewhere for it to work out. You wrote

```
w(n+1) = w(n) + alpha*x(n)*e(n)
```

which I'll rewrite as

```
new_weight = curr_weight + learning_rate * gradient
```

where

```
gradient = X * transpose(e)
```

the dot product of the error vector and the input data vector.

As for why I decided to call it "gradient", see the [derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_mean_squares_filter#Derivation) of this update rule --- the update rule comes from gradient descent on a cost function given by the mean square error. After "enough" iterations, the weights you have will be the weights that minimize the mean square error, hence the name.

> Now, what do I do with this new weight vector that I have created? Do I apply this weight vector to a new set of "testing data"?
>   Does the "converged" weight vector now become the weight vector to try and classify any unseen data?

Yes, exactly! Let's call the final set of weights `final_weights` and suppose it has `k` entries, where `k` has to be the dimension of each datapoint (so your input data is perhaps a `n-by-k` matrix where each row represents a `k`-dimensional datapoint, so that the matrix dimensions work out).

Then you can generate predictions on unseen datapoints `X ~ 1-by-k` with

```
 prediction = final_weights * X
```

and `prediction` will be a floating point value. (You said you wanted 0,+1,-1 as your target values, but you will need different strategies depending on whether these are unordered labels versus ordered values; i.e. if they represent temperatures, you might have luck with taking floors and ceilings of `prediction`, but if they represent unordered categories, you might have to train three separate models, each indicating likelihood of falling into a particular category. Leave a comment if this seems unclear and I'll add an edit.)

If you really wanted to, you could use any arbitrary set of weights in the above; it will just be the case that you will generate awful predictions with a weight vector consisting entirely of, say, zeros or consisting entirely of random numbers. The training process (i.e. all those iterated updates) is there to ensure that you have a halfway-decent weight vector, i.e. one that will generate reasonably good predictions based on past training data.

> With this weight vector, how do I apply it to a new data set?

Apply it to the new, unseen data one datapoint at a time using the prediction rule above.

> Where does gradient descent, mean-square errors, and convergence fit into this?

Gradient descent is implemented by the update rule mentioned above. Consider how the cost function

```
 Cost(weights) := mean-square-error(weights)
```

is a function of the weights you're using; you want to minimize the cost, so you use gradient descent to find the weights that do that. We say that the weights "converge" because they'll stop updating when you're at the optimal set of weights, even if you continue iterating. The reason for this is that the error will decrease to zero, and when that happens, your update rule will be

```
new_weights = old_weights + (learning_rate * 0)
```

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Fantastic response, ptsw.  It makes so much sense!  Thanks :)

Comment: If it helped you out, I'd appreciate it if you selected it as the answer... If only for the points :-)